# After updating a record via store.sync()  in Ext JS 4, the record is doubled

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

My json-store contains one record. This record is dirty after changing a field and correctly after store.sync() a POST is sended with action=update and the record data in the body.

On the server side I commit the update and send back the record (with success:true) as it was posted originally (all fields are included).

Afterwards the store has doubled the record, which means the store has now two (2) identical records (same id etc.).

I played around with all options I could imagine of (root [on/off], idProperty (set/unset) etc.) the effect is always the same.

Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason for the described misbehavior. Within my model I had overwritten the constructor like this:

```
constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent([config]);
},
```

I do not really remember why I did this, but since I have deleted the constructor, everything works fine. But due to my relative inexperience, I don't know why this works.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same issue and my theory is that the id matching on the returned record is not happening properly. What I mean by that is in my opinion idProperty type must be an int for example instead of a string or some such calamity. I have not been able to prove this one way or another but I do have a workaround. Here is how I "handled" this issue:

1). Do not send back the data, just send success message.
2). Clear the dirty flag manually with the following store listener:

```
listeners : {
            write: function(store, operation, opts){
                console.log('request wrote!');
                //workaround to sync up store records with just completed operation
                Ext.each(operation.records, function(record){
                    if (record.dirty) {
                        record.commit();
                    }
                    /*if (record.phantom) {
                        record.phantom=false;
                    }*/
                });
                store.load();
            },
            delay: 2000
        }
```

---

**EDIT**: I asked this question a while ago on premium forums and the answer I got is that it's supposed to work and here is an example that is supposed to prove it. 
http://pastebin.com/z3gekQDn  Please note the id mapping in the model.

Comment: This works, but different as described... When I send back "{success:true}" only. Everything works fine AND I do not have to clear the dirty flags. It is done automatically. Is this bug or feature?

Comment: ExtJS has a ton of bugs that are really just "features"... =/

Comment: please see the edit on my answer for a supposedly working example.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your server returns an array of records. If you have only one record put it in an array and send it back.

Check out this [demo](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase#RowEditableGridWindow) with Firebug.

Comment: This definitely does not work. If I update two records at the same time and send them back as array both are duplicated in the store. Sending the record(s) in an array does not change anything. --> See also my comment on the other answer.